# Adding a reminder on Google Calendar from my Android application

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

Hi I'm new to android application development. I went through research but I can't find a tutorial on how to put an event to Google Calendar from my android application. So basically I just want a simple method on how to do this. The requirements that the user will input and will come from my android application are : title, location, due date and time, and details.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Events can be inserted into Google Calendar(from android application) by using INSERT intent or can be inserted to calendar directly. This is the [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intent-insert) which describes in detail about the rules to insert an event. Also, it has sample example of inserting an event.

Answer (score 0):

*This might help you.*
****This code sends you to the reminder activity of the suitable application that is installed in your device.****

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
intent.setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI);
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, __title__);
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, __Start Time__);
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, __End Time__);
```